# Angular Modal Window not working for the life of me

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-services, angular-controller, modal-window

I'm very new to Angular.js.

I've taken the necessary elements from this tutorial on modal windows within Angular.js: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/13/angularjs-custom-modal-example-tutorial

Isolated, I can get this code to work, but after porting it to my website, I just can't get it to work.

In Jason's code, he has a file called index.controller.js, and although I've ported this file to my own page, I don't believe it's firing. Here's index.controller.js:

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Home.IndexController', Controller);

    function Controller(ModalService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.openModal = openModal;
        vm.closeModal = closeModal;

        function openModal(id){
            ModalService.Open(id);
        }

        function closeModal(id){
            ModalService.Close(id);
        }
    }

})();
```

On my own page, I have all the controllers contained within app.js. Here's how it's laid out:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider

     .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
     })

 .state('screenings', {
    url: '/screenings',
    templateUrl: 'pages/screenings.php',
    controller: 'Home.IndexController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
 })

...

});
```

You can see that, in the second .state, I'm attempting to call on the index.controller.js file for this particular partial. For some reason, though, the code under screeningsController (down below) is the code that's firing.

Further down in the same app.js file, I have my controllers:

```
...

app.controller('screeningsController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){

    $scope.popup = function() {

    // assign a message to the $scope
    $scope.message = 'Hello World!';

    // use the $log service to output the message in a console
    $log.log($scope.message);

    };

}]);

...
```

Is there any way I can somehow integrate what's in the index.controller.js file into my screeningsController in the app.js? I've been trying to get a modal window working on my site for about a week now. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The ngRoute declared at the top of the app.js file might not be necessary anymore. I was using ngRoute prior to working with Jason's code. He was using ui-router, so I implemented that.

Comment: Where is `Home.IndexController` defined? Did you intend to have route "/screenings" use controller `screeningsController`? If so you need to update the route to be `controller: 'screeningsController'`.

Comment: I was testing to see if it would use index.controller.js somehow instead of screeningsController. I originally had it as `controller: 'screeningsController'`. Even as it's written now, it still seems to be firing screeningsController.

Comment: In Jason's code, he names the controller `'Home.IndexController'`, so I tried to see if somehow this would execute index.controller.js. I'm not really sure how index.controller.js is being executed.

Comment: The name of the file doesn't matter with angular, its the string identifier that is key. The `controller` property value of your route definition needs to match the identifier you specified in `app.controller('someIdentifierGoesHere', [function() {}])`. You'll likely need to share your HTML to determine if you are trigger controllers to instantiate via directive such as `ng-controller`.

Comment: If its still firing screeningsController, your browser must be using the old version of your js, it happens sometime.

Comment: @ukn I've been hitting "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in Chrome - would it still fire screeningsController after that?

Comment: If you do not have `app.controller('Home.IndexController'` somewhere in the files for angular application, then that route with `controller: 'Home.IndexController'` will simply not work.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Oh man, I see in the partial it says `<div id="screenings" ng-controller="screeningsController">` at the very top. I bet that's what you're referring to. Ugh

Comment: So if I change this to `<div id="screenings" ng-controller="Home.IndexController">` it would potentially fire the code within index.controller.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a controller with identifier `Home.IndexController`. Based on the route configuration this will instantiate when you navigate to "/screenings". Call the `popup()` function attached to $scope of `Home.IndexController` via a directive us `ng-click` for testing. As you have specified `controllerAs` make sure to reference controller properties and methods prefixed with `vm.`.

You do not need both `index.controller.js` and `app.js` both loaded. It looks everything you'd need is defined in `app.js`, so just make sure that is being loaded in your application. Eventually you'd want to separate these into different files and/or modules as necessary.

Try the following:

**Configuration:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider

     .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
     })
     .state('screenings', {
        url: '/screenings',
        templateUrl: 'pages/screenings.php',
        controller: 'Home.IndexController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
     });

     ...
});
```

**Home.IndexController**:

```
app.controller('Home.IndexController', ['$log', function($log){

    var vm = this;

    vm.message = '';

    vm.popup = function() {
        vm.message = 'foobar';
        $log.log(vm.message);
    }
}]);
```

**Screenings Template:**

```
<!-- Home.IndexController /screenings template -->
<div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.popup()"></button>
</div>
```

This also assumes you have `ui-view` specified somewhere in your main template like `index.html` or equivalent:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- Vendor and Custom scripts added here -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My apologies,pasted the wrong code for index.controller.js, but fixed it above.So if I paste the code `function Controller(ModalService) { var vm = this;

        vm.openModal = openModal;
        vm.closeModal = closeModal;

        function openModal(id){
            ModalService.Open(id);
        }

        function closeModal(id){
            ModalService.Close(id);
        }
    }` within screeningsController, in app.js, that should fire? Given that ng-controller is set to screeningsController, and the controller for the "screenings" .state is also set to screeningsController?

Comment: the "Hello World" statement executes, but the function taken from index.controller.js does not.

Comment: ui-router with definitions for specified controllers to use for a given route almost entirely eliminate the need for ng-controller within your template. I'd recommend taking out ng-controller and instead put the logic you need into `Home.IndexController` or whatever you end up calling it.

Comment: I'll make a demonstration, please hold

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've been trying to get this to work for a week of full-time work. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Here is a link to [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0tpfogqPFNpBUN6ahpR2?p=preview) showing ui-router as well as multiple controllers with controllerAs in action. The files can technically be named **anything**, just make sure they are referenced/loaded in `index.html`. Avoid the use of `ng-controller` as ui-router helps load the proper controller for the defined route. Focus on naming your controller files inline with what the controllers are identified as.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Thank you very much!